# What is the problem with this model parameter estimation algorithm?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, estimation, parameter-estimation

In a statistical  model with parameters $\theta$ and unobserved laten variables $Z$, the model likelihood is

$$L(\theta;X)=Pr(X|\theta)=\sum_ZPr(X,Z|\theta)$$

The standard way to estimate $\theta$ is to maximize this likelihood (e.g. using EM or so). However if this estimation is computational intractable, can I maximize $Pr(X,Z|\theta)$ w.r.t both $Z$ and $\theta$, and use this estimated $\theta$ as the model parameter? Does this method have a name? What is the main drawback or problem with this method?

Comment: Is the joint pmf/pdf of X,Z under θ known? Or, if I am not much mistaken, you are suitably choosing the joint pmf/pdf?

Comment: the formulation of the joint distribution is known. but the summation over Z is very difficult. This is the problem I encountered.